# How to convert .xvg file to .xyz file (split one line to multiple lines)?

Tags: awk

I want to convert a file `vel.xvg`

```
0      0.303345        0.0430715       1.46423      0.354741        0.124701         1.49059        0.320466        1.5482      1.53037     0.0892707       1.07608     0.545043        0.000847689     1.07834     0.498392        0.1477      1.14895     0.509314
1      0.301998        0.0438025       1.4651       0.356303        0.122887         1.49332        0.319646        1.54791     1.52995     0.0896649       1.07605     0.54495        0.000783547      1.07822     0.499174        0.14217      1.1499    0.50264
2      0.300672        0.0444949       1.46599      0.358753        0.120221         1.49586        0.31959         1.54831     1.53015     0.0900906       1.07607     0.544848       0.000537069      1.07801     0.500391        0.136618     1.15043     0.49682
```

to file `vel.xyz`:

```
6
i =  0
O   0.303345  0.0430715  1.46423
H   0.354741  0.124701  1.49059
H   0.320466  1.5482  1.53037
O   0.0892707  1.07608  0.545043
H   0.000847689  1.07834  0.498392
H   0.1477  1.14895  0.509314
6
i =  1
O   0.301998  0.0438025  1.4651
H   0.356303  0.122887  1.49332
H   0.319646  1.54791  1.52995
O   0.0896649  1.07605  0.54495
H   0.000783547  1.07822  0.499174
H   0.14217  1.1499  0.50264
6
i =  2
O   0.300672  0.0444949  1.46599
H   0.358753  0.120221  1.49586
H   0.31959  1.54831  1.53015
O   0.0900906  1.07607  0.544848
H   0.000537069  1.07801  0.500391
H   0.136618  1.15043  0.49682
```

First, I used the command

```
awk -v f=2  '{print "6","\n","i = ",$1}{for(i=f;i<=NF;i++){printf("%s%s ",$i,(i-1)%3?",":"\n")}}' vel.xvg > tmp
```

The output `tmp` is:

```
6
i =  0
0.303345, 0.0430715, 1.46423
0.354741, 0.124701, 1.49059
0.320466, 1.5482, 1.53037
0.0892707, 1.07608, 0.545043
0.000847689, 1.07834, 0.498392
0.1477, 1.14895, 0.509314
6
i =  1
0.301998, 0.0438025, 1.4651
0.356303, 0.122887, 1.49332
0.319646, 1.54791, 1.52995
0.0896649, 1.07605, 0.54495
0.000783547, 1.07822, 0.499174
0.14217, 1.1499, 0.50264
6
i =  2
0.300672, 0.0444949, 1.46599
0.358753, 0.120221, 1.49586
0.31959, 1.54831, 1.53015
0.0900906, 1.07607, 0.544848
0.000537069, 1.07801, 0.500391
0.136618, 1.15043, 0.49682
```

Then,I add the label `O` and `H` for some lines with code

```
awk -v t=8  '{if((NR%t>2)&&(NR%t)%3==0) print "O ",$0; else if(((NR%t>2)&& (NR%t)%3==1) ||((NR%t>2)&&(NR%t)%3==2)) print "H ",$0; else{print}}' tmp | awk -v t=8 '{if(NR%t==0) print "H ",$0; else{print}}' > vel.xyz
```

and get the output

```
6
i =  0
O  0.303345, 0.0430715, 1.46423
H   0.354741, 0.124701, 1.49059
H   0.320466, 1.5482, 1.53037
O   0.0892707, 1.07608, 0.545043
H   0.000847689, 1.07834, 0.498392
H   0.1477, 1.14895, 0.509314
6
i =  1
O  0.301998, 0.0438025, 1.4651
H   0.356303, 0.122887, 1.49332
H   0.319646, 1.54791, 1.52995
O   0.0896649, 1.07605, 0.54495
H   0.000783547, 1.07822, 0.499174
H   0.14217, 1.1499, 0.50264 
6
i =  2 
O  0.300672, 0.0444949, 1.46599
H   0.358753, 0.120221, 1.49586
H   0.31959, 1.54831, 1.53015
O   0.0900906, 1.07607, 0.544848
H   0.000537069, 1.07801, 0.500391
H   0.136618, 1.15043, 0.49682
```

Could someone suggest a better and clean way to solve this problem?

Comment: You are missing `(` in your `if((NR%365)-2)%3==1)`.

Comment: It's as @luoluo said. And it would have been obvious to you if you wrote your script in an editor (publicity for [VIm](http://www.vim.org/) and [emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)) with syntax colourization ;^)

Comment: After testing, I find the following code works for this problem:       `awk -v t=365 '{if((NR%t>2)&&(NR%t)%3==0) printf("%s%s%s%s%s","O ",$1,$2,$3,"\n"); else if(((NR%t>2)&& (NR%t)%3==1) ||((NR%t>2)&&(NR%t)%3==2)) printf("%s%s%s%s%s","H ",$1,$2,$3,"\n"); else{print}}' tmp | awk -v t=365 '{if(NR%t==0) print "H ",$0; else{print}}' > vel.xyz`

Comment: I wonder why you know you can simply use `print` in some places (e.g. `print "H ",$0`) but you think you need to use `printf` in others (`printf("%s%s%s%s%s","H ",$1,$2,$3,"\n")` vs `print "H",$1,$2,$3`). The script can be written much more simply but we can't help you without testable sample input and expected output (e.g. get rid of all the `...`s and make sure they match pecisely.)

Comment: @EdMorton  Yes. What I have done are (1): `awk -v f=2 '{print "363","\n","i = ",$1}{for(i=f;i<=NF;i++){printf("%s%s ",$i,(i-1)%3?",":"\n")}}' vel.xvg> vel.xyz`  and (2): 
`awk -v t=365 '{if((NR%t>2)&&(NR%t)%3==0) print "O ",$0; else if(((NR%t>2)&& (NR%t)%3==1) ||((NR%t>2)&&(NR%t)%3==2)) print "H ",$0; else{print}}' vel.xyz | awk -v t=365 '{if(NR%t==0) print "H ",$0; else{print}}' > vel2.xyz`   These two command give the result I list above. Each block has 363+2=365 lines.  I hope to have a better way for this problem. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Instead of just hoping for a better way, edit your question to have testable sample input and output and a clear explanation of how the input fields map to the output fields (do not assume we know or care what ".xvg" or any other format means - it's all just rows and columns of fields to us) and you almost certainly WILL get a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should be self explanatory

```
awk '{print 6"\ni = "$1; 
      for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=3) 
          print (i%9==2?"O":"H")"\t",$i,$(i+1),$(i+2)}'
```

`6` is hard coded, I'm guessing it's the number of records.  Breaking by groups of 3 and prefixing based on the first of a triple 3 records; tab separate from the numbers.

Comment: 's answer is exact and nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { numCols=3 }
{
    numRows = (NF-1) / numCols
    print numRows ORS "i =", $1
    fldNr = 1
    for (rowNr=1;rowNr<=numRows;rowNr++) {
        printf (rowNr%numCols==1?"O":"H")
        for (colNr=1;colNr<=numCols;colNr++) {
            printf "%s%s", OFS, $(++fldNr)
        }
        print ""
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
6
i = 0
O 0.303345 0.0430715 1.46423
H 0.354741 0.124701 1.49059
H 0.320466 1.5482 1.53037
O 0.0892707 1.07608 0.545043
H 0.000847689 1.07834 0.498392
H 0.1477 1.14895 0.509314
6
i = 1
O 0.301998 0.0438025 1.4651
H 0.356303 0.122887 1.49332
H 0.319646 1.54791 1.52995
O 0.0896649 1.07605 0.54495
H 0.000783547 1.07822 0.499174
H 0.14217 1.1499 0.50264
6
i = 2
O 0.300672 0.0444949 1.46599
H 0.358753 0.120221 1.49586
H 0.31959 1.54831 1.53015
O 0.0900906 1.07607 0.544848
H 0.000537069 1.07801 0.500391
H 0.136618 1.15043 0.49682
```

Comment: It works! @Ed Morton When the record is much larger than 6. I use                                                                                       `{
     print 6 ORS "i =", $1
         fldNr = 1
     for(j=1; j<=6/3;j++)
     {prt("O"); prt("H"); prt("H")} 
     }

     function prt(let) {
          printf let
       for (i=1;i<=3;i++) {
                printf "%s%s", OFS, $(++fldNr)
             }
          print ""
         }`

Comment: Yes!!@Ed Morton That is very nice! Thanks!

Comment: I modified it to use variables numRows and numCols that you can set/calculate for however many rows and cols you need.